# how to call a method in another project from a class library's class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, dll

I want to call a method that is written in a class library and I want to access it in a web project's page load. I have added the reference of that class library. But unable to bind that method to `GridView`.

My code is:

```
GridView1.DataSource = CRMFullProject.Databasebase.GetAllCustomers();
```

…here CRMFullProject is project name and databasebase is public class in it.

Comment: What's the error?  You should be able to access any public classes in a referenced assembly.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If yes - then it's better to show errortext. If no errors - then specify what's wrong.

Comment: error: the type or namespace "CRMFullproject" could not be found.are you missing an assembly reference or using directive..please help

Comment: @AhmadRaza Do you have a `using` statement for the right namespace?

Comment: Are you sure your namespace containing `Databasebase` has name `CRMFullProject` exactly as project? Usually it is so - but not necessary. Go to the `Databasebase` definition and check its namespace.

Comment: yes it has the namespace CRMFullProject

Comment: CRMFullProject does not exist in the current context

Comment: it is throughing error on "using CRMFullProject;"

Answer (score 0):

To call a method from another library.
Type the namespace ,also dont forget to import that reference into your solution explorer.

Comment: i have done both these steps but getting error that "CRMFullProject" doesn't exists in the current context

Comment: are you pretty sure your method is set as public?

Comment: 100% sure..the code that i have uploaded comes with intellisence but afterwards gives error

Answer (score 0):

Here I believe your Project name is CRMFullProject and there's a class in that project called Databasebase right? You can call GetAllCustomers() like that if it's a static method. Otherwise you need an instance of Databasebase first.

```
var dbbase = new Databasebase(); //If there's a default constructor
GridView1.DataSource = dbbase.GetAllCustomers();
```

You don't need to reference CRMFullProject, if you have imported that namespace to your code, using `using`. You must import the namespace 
CRMFullProject in order to use classes defined in that namespace, which is in the Project CRMFullProject.

if `GetAllCustomers()` method is static :

```
GridView1.DataSource = Databasebase.GetAllCustomers();
```

Comment: error from your code:cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify with a type name instead

Comment: That probably means, your GetAllCustomers method is static. is it? I said that in my answer, answer edited considering it's a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to be redundant with other answers, but you need to first add a reference to "CRMFullproject" in the project you want to call the method in. You then need to have

`using CRMFullProject;`

at the top of the class you're calling the method in. And lastly, if `GetAllCustomers` is static, you can call it the way you did. If it is not static, then you need to create an Databasebase object, and then access the method through the object. Heres an example:

```
Databasebase dbbase = new Databasebase();
dbbase.GetAllCustomers();
```

Also, a common mistake I've seen is classes declared like this:

```
class Databasebase
{
//methods
}
```

because this actually defaults to private. so even if the method is public, you still need to declare the class like this:

```
public class Databasebase
{
//methods
}
```

so that the class will be public as well.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Check does reference exist in the solution explorer of your application, as the program exception message is
"CRMFullproject" could not be found.are you missing an assembly reference.

Step 2.
For being able to call something from another library add 
using CRMFullproject;

Step 3.
Rebuild the application (or first clean and then again build).

P.S. I should give like comments, but as I don't have reputation points sending it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

My code was alright but the error was that the target framework of the class library project and the target framework of my web project was different..i changed that to same and it is working fine now....
Many many thanks to all who gave their ideas